# Expand integer ranges in pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
d = {'value': ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g', 'h'],\
     'id'   : ['0101', '0208', '0103', '0405', '0105,0116,0117',
                '0108-0110', '0231, 0232, 0133-0150', '0155, 0152-0154, 0151']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>>
       value                     id
0      a                   0101
1      b                   0208
2      c                   0103
3      d                   0405
4      e                   0105
5      e                   0116
6      e                   0117
7      f                   0108
8      f                   0109
9      f                   0110
10     g  0231, 0232, 0133-0150
11     h  0155, 0152-0154, 0151
```

but I need to expand these IDs so that each row is a single number, so it looks more like:

```
   value    id
0      a  0101
1      b  0208
2      c  0103
3      d  0405
4      e  0105
5      e  0116
6      e  0117
7      f  0108
8      f  0109
9      f  0110
10     g   ...
```

where each row is duplicated where the IDs were grouped (with the ranges expanded, and leading zeros preserved for IDs less than 4 digits).

I've got as far as

```
df['id'].str.split(",")
df['id'].str.contains("-")
```

but I can't think of a good way to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think your sample is broken or incomplete

Comment: Yeah sorry, also need the ranges expanded, have edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a little routine to flatten your ranges, and then repeat values from the original as necessary.

```
from itertools import chain

flattened = []
for x in df['id'].str.split(r',\s*'):
    flattened.append([])
    for y in x:
        if '-' in y:
            start, end = pd.to_numeric(y.split('-'))
            flattened[-1].extend(pd.RangeIndex(start, end+1))
        else: 
            flattened[-1].append(int(y))

repeats = [len(f) for f in flattened]
```

```
df_flat = pd.DataFrame({
        'value': df.value.repeat(repeats).values, 
        'id': list(chain.from_iterable(flattened))})
df_flat.tail(10)

   value   id
25     g  146
26     g  147
27     g  148
28     g  149
29     g  150
30     h  155
31     h  152
32     h  153
33     h  154
34     h  151
```

---

This turns out to be pretty performant, even for larger data.

```
df_ = df
df = pd.concat([df_] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit flatten(df)  # Function running code above.
244 ms ± 15.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I can't really read or understand it but it works perfectly thanks and appears to be efficient

Comment: does this solution work for n>2 columns? I can't seem to make it work for my real world example with the following error: 
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0       0       0                                     ...\n1       0       0                                     ...\n2       0       ...
`

Comment: @BenJones It is currently fitted to work for two columns but you can always open a follow up question asking how to generalise it (hint: try using `df.apply`)

Comment: before I open up a new question, I've fixed the hardcoded dictionary part in `df_flat = pd.DataFrame({` ... etc with a dictionary list comprehension but can't see where else the problem is, which line is the part that needs an apply? Much appreciated

Comment: @BenJones Hmm, okay, can you tell me exactly which line throws this error?

Comment: The problem comes at `for y in x:` but I think the problem is the split line `df['id'].str.split(r',\s*'): ` but I'm unfamiliar with the function and regex on the whole

Comment: @BenJones The regex splits on commas followed by optional spaces. Your error still does not make sense to me in the context of the explanation given. Best thing to do would be to open a new Q... :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185844/discussion-between-ben-jones-and-coldspeed).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it:

```
s = (df['id'].str.split(r"[, ]|[-]")
             .apply(pd.Series)
             .stack()
             .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))

df.drop('id', axis =1).join(s.to_frame()).reset_index(drop=True)

 value     0
0      a  0101
1      b  0208
2      c  0103
3      d  0405
4      e  0105
5      e  0116
6      e  0117
7      f  0108
8      f  0109
9      f  0110
10     g  0231
11     g  0232
12     g  0133
13     g  0150
14     h  0155
15     h  0152
16     h  0154
17     h  0151
```

Comment: While technically not wrong, `apply(pd.Series)` is known to have some serious performance issues... and compounded with stack... *whistle* don't let the succinctness deceive you :-)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware :). I'll also add a more efficient solution in case the dataframe is large.

Comment: Dataframe is not large (~1000 rows) but I also need the ranges to be filled out, ie 0133-0150 becomes 0133, 0134, 0135... etc

Comment: Oh, I see. Will modify current solution

Comment: I appreciate how clean and readable this is but doesn't currently quite solve the problem, thanks though @nixon